# Is it legal/accepted to copy content for documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, syntax-section

How do I know if it is legal to copy content from a website to a documentation section or an answer? I am not a lawyer nor a native English speaker.

As an concrete example: Is it OK to copy the syntax from [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) to the [MERGE documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/4550/merge#t=201706231044298600209)?

- Should I copy the content?
- Should I link to the source?
- Should I try to reproduce the content (that seems pointless for a syntax definition)?

Comment: No, perhaps, no. If you can't make existing documentation better, having more will not help.

Comment: Regardless of legal, some day in the future the MS doc page will be updated, and then we have an outdated piece on 'our documentation'. Copying information for the sole purpose of having it here, too, is something you should not do

Comment: @tim-castelijns I get your standpoint and i support it. Copied content is dead. On the other hand i was just told the [exact opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659584/suppress-group-header-when-no-record-below/44669153?noredirect=1#comment76339994_44669153).

Comment: That is something different. Providing an answer based on external documentation is not the same as copying documentation from site A to site B

Comment: Notice that person said *"summarize"*, not "copy".

Comment: @cody That's what i meant with my last bullet point. But summarizing a grammar seems difficult to me.

Comment: I was talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659584/suppress-group-header-when-no-record-below/44669153?noredirect=1#comment76339994_44669153), mentioned in your previous comment.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**When in doubt, assume it is not legal to copy *anything*.**

The major exception is when you're copying from a Stack Overflow post, in which case it is legal, so long as you comply with the [license agreement](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which requires that you [provide explicit attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) (i.e., give credit to) the original author and include a link to their answer.

Otherwise, unless you can find an explicit license on the page and ensure that you comply with all the terms of that license, assume you cannot copy the content. As a workaround, you will need to put the information in your own words, and give credit to the original source for inspiration.

But stop and think about whether the information you are considering copying is really what we want to appear in Stack Overflow Documentation. In the context of your specific example, this is emphatically *not* what we want. **We don't need to reproduce official documentation that already exists on Microsoft's site.** For other information that you might think would be useful to have in Documentation (such as example code from someone's blog post), since you have to put it in your own words anyway, this gives you the perfect opportunity to adapt/tailor it to our format.

Comment: This seems reasonable. In this specific context: Should the already copied content be replaced by a link to its source? Or should the link be anywhere else? My intend is to make it easy for someone looking at that subject to get the syntax definition.

Comment: BTW, some of docs.microsoft.com content, including .Net docs and at least some of Azure docs, is licensed under CC-BY for text and MIT for code, which I think should be compatible with CC-BY-SA used by SO docs. Though this does not seem to apply to the SQL docs in question here. You can find this out by clicking on the Edit button (if there is one) and looking for the license in the GitHub repo you are send to.

Answer (score 2):

### Documentation content follows the same rules as Q&A.

The [Content Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) explains:

> **Copyright.** Using copyrighted material does not constitute infringement in all cases. In general, however, users should be careful when using copyrighted content without the permission of those who created it. It is our policy to [respond to notices of alleged infringement](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#designatedagent) that comply with the [Digital Millennium Copyright Act ("DMCA")](http://www.loc.gov/copyright/legislation/dmca.pdf).

That's from a legal perspective. However, Stack Overflow (both the community and the company) believe authors be given [additional courtesies](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing):

1. It should be clear what content is being copied,
2. The original source should be credited, and
3. A link to the original should be provided.

### We still need to clarify the relationship with official documentation.

Before the public beta, I talked with several companies who were interested in using Documentation for their products. (You can see some of their logos on the [launch announcement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/21/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/).) One question most everyone had was how official documentation (created by the team responsible for the technology being documented) should interact with Stack Overflow Documentation. We still don't have a good answer.

On the one hand, we don't want to duplicate all the hard work of maintaining documentation. And on the other, we'd love to ["provide product developers with a documentation platform that is smoother and easier to maintain than their own web sites or GitHub readmes"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation#comment474490_349410). On the gripping hand, user-contributed content doesn't mesh well with official content. Many companies asked for some way to lock out community edits or privilege employee edits.

In our early research into [where to take Documentation next](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation) suggests developers appreciate the depth and authority of official references. But they would also like to have access to knowledge hard-won by experience. We don't yet know what strategy we will pursue but we are looking for ways to connect our Documentation with other resources. Perhaps we could take a page from Google results and embed previews of other documentation (and [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348410/1438)). We still need to do more research and user interviews, however.

---

At any rate,  you can, if needed, quote outside material and [properly reference it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Or you can just link to it. Or you can rewrite in your own words. In the future we plan to provide better ways to help readers locate and understand authoritative documentation.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but you *do* mention it in this answer, so I'll go ahead and ask. Whatever happened to the partnership/collaboration on Docs with Microsoft? It seems that they completely ignored your product and instead rolled out [their own](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/) wiki-style documentation. And, frankly, I can't blame them; my experience with both shows that MS's implementation works *way* better. I realize you guys have since, um, gone back to the drawing board with Documentation, but where does that leave the partnerships? I haven't seen any evidence of their participation.

Comment: Insight- and helpful answer, too.

Comment: @CodyGray: If I recall the timing correctly, we were talking with one part of Microsoft while another part of Microsoft rolled out the new documentation system you mentioned. We asked launch partners to contribute a few topics before launch. We'd hoped they would continue working with us post-launch, but it didn't happen. (Probably because we had so many growing pains early on.) We'll _probably_ revisit those companies once we have something else to show them.